# Comments and includes being collapsed when opening a .h or .cpp file in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, editor, visual-studio-2019

I have a Visual Studio 2019 solution that has many C++ projects. In one of the project, whenever I open up a .h or .cpp file, all of the comments and the includes at the top of the file are initially open but collapse after a couple of seconds. There is only one project that I have seen in this solution that does that.

I normally keep all the methods in the .cpp files collapsed and the editor does remember which methods were open when I close and re-open the file. I have searched the project .vcxproj, .filters, and .user files but can't find the setting that would cause this behavior. I recently deleted the solution .vs directory to fix a different problem so the setting do not appear to be kept there.

Has anyone else seen this behavior and know where the setting is to turn it off?

Comment: Would anyone want a Visual Studio 2020? Pretty much everything else 2020's sent our way has be utter <expletive deleted>.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2019 nearly every day but I don't often use the code collapse features. I am not sure why you have this behavior.

Comment: I suggest that you could submit this question to [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).